# Target 'Genome' was rejected as an implicit dependency because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386'

Tags: swift, build, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an app with `cocoapods 1.0.0` and `Xcode 7.3.1` but there's an issue with architecture.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

[image]

Comment: what are your deployment targets set to?

Comment: All the deployment targets are set to 9.0 but the architecture is set to 9.3 and there is no option for the 9.0

Answer (score 0):

You must provide architectures for all devices available to the target OS you are building for. Likewise, the libraries must do the same. A mismatch will cause this error.